# How do I get Twitter4J to stream posts with a Photo?

Tags: android, twitter, twitter4j

Using Twitter4J i can able to get the home_line tweets by using the method

```
    Twitter.getHomeTimeline();
```

I want to retrieve the tweets which contains photo tags , i came up with the solution FilterQuery but i do not know how to use this FilterQuery class to get the tweets which contains photo tag.

Please help me in this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is this example by neufuture, using Processing(P5) and twitter4j. It does this. When i run it i changed the test in draw() from   `if(imageLoaded)` to `if(img != null)` at line 42 and it stops getting null pointer errors. Besides that it is a very good example in dealing with images urls. 
hope it helps.

https://github.com/neufuture/SimpleTwitterStream/